# How can I access the source artifacts of my gradle compile dependencies?

Tags: gradle

I have written the following task, which extracts all the compile dependencies for each of my sub-projects and puts them in a per sub-project directory:

```
task exportCompileLibs << {
  subprojects.each { iSubProject ->
    iSubProject.configurations.findAll{it.name == "compile"}.each{ jConfig ->
      println "copying compile libs for ${iSubProject.name}..."
      copy {
        into "${iSubProject.buildDir}/gradle-lib-export"
        from jConfig
        eachFile {println it.name}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to extend this to also export the source artifacts that Gradle does already know about (I can see the source jars in the cache directory), I just can't figure out how to use the object model to get a handle to them.

The IDEA and Eclipse plugins seem to be able to do this (they point the project files they build directly into the gradle cache), but I can't figure out how to do it - and looking at the IDE plugin source code, it looks... tricky.  I'm hoping there's something obvious that I'm missing in the gradle DSL or API.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31451648/300053 for a solution that don't rely on IDE plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for at least an interim solution to this, the following seems to be doing pretty much exactly what I want at the moment.

You have to apply the IDEA plugin to the build.gradle file for each project you want to export the dependencies for:

> apply plugin: 'idea'

And then define this task:

```
task exportDependencies << {
  def deps = project.extensions.getByType(IdeaModel).module.resolveDependencies()
  copy {
    from deps*.classes.file
    into "${buildDir}/gradle-lib-export/libs"
  }

  copy {
    from deps*.sources.file
    into "${buildDir}/gradle-lib-export/sources"
  }
}
```

And here's my horrific hack so I don't have to apply the plugin for each sub-project:

```
task exportDependencies(description: "export project dependency jars") << {
  subprojects.each { Project iSubProject ->
    String target = "${iSubProject.buildDir}/gradle-lib-export"

    IdeaPlugin ideaPlugin = new IdeaPlugin()
    ideaPlugin.apply(iSubProject)
    Set<Dependency> deps = ideaPlugin.model.module.resolveDependencies()

    println "exporting dependencies for $iSubProject.name into $target"
    copy {
      from deps*.classes.file
      into "${target}/libs"
      eachFile { println "lib -> $it.name" }
    }
    copy {
      from deps*.sources.file
      into "${target}/sources"
      eachFile{ println "source -> $it.name" }
    }
  }
}
```

+10 points for not cluttering my build task list with stuff I don't want, -several million points for *ewwwww*.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a simpler way than what the IDE plugins are doing. This will hopefully change in the future.